# Sub Menu items overlapping with Main Menu in navigation

Tags: html, css

i'm new with css. i'm trying to make a navigation menu with sub items, but i think i'm missing something. the sub items are over lapping with the main items.

so the way i see it that the top list items are floated so are removed from the normal content flow. Which means i need to clear the float after  so that the sub items display under the main items.

But its not working for me..Any ideas

https://jsfiddle.net/madubuko/szqk5be9/

```
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">News</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a>Football News</a></li>
                        <li><a>Team News</a></li>
                        <li><a>Players News</a></li>
                        <li><a>Other News</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About us</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

Please Replace this code with your old code :

```css
* {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

body {
  background-image: url("../images/background.jpeg");
}

#container {
  width: 100%;
}
nav {}

#container nav ul {
  list-style: none;
}

#container nav ul li {
  float: left;
  width: 100px;
  height: 40px;
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
  text-align: center;
  border-right: solid #fff 1px;
  border-bottom: solid #fff 1px;
  padding-top: 7px;
  opacity: 0.8;
   position: relative;
}

#container nav ul li a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

#container nav ul li ul li {
  clear: both;
}
#container nav ul li ul {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    display: none;
}
#container nav ul li:hover ul{
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/corecss.css" type="text/css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="container">
      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">News</a>
            <ul>
              <li><a>Football News</a></li>
              <li><a>Team News</a></li>
              <li><a>Players News</a></li>
              <li><a>Other News</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">About us</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: @OgbobeBuko Welcome Sir... :)

Comment: @OgbobeBuko please see this link and accept my answer.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/LkiIZ.png

Answer (score 1):

Add Some CSS

```
#container nav ul li {
  float: left;
  width: 100px;
  height: 40px;
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
  text-align: center;
  border-right: solid #fff 1px;
  border-bottom: solid #fff 1px;
  padding-top: 7px;
  opacity: 0.8;
  position: relative;/*Add This Property*/
}

#container nav ul li ul {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    display: none;
}
#container nav ul li:hover ul{
  display:block;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/szqk5be9/2/

Answer (score 0):

You can set it using `position`, check updated snippet below

```css
* {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

body {
  background-image: url("../images/background.jpeg");
}

#container {
  width: 100%;
}

nav {}

#container nav ul {
  list-style: none;
}

#container nav ul li {
  float: left;
  width: 100px;
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
  text-align: center;
  border-right: solid #fff 1px;
  border-bottom: solid #fff 1px;
  padding: 7px 5px;
  opacity: 0.8;
  position: relative;
}

#container nav ul li a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

#container nav ul li ul li {
  clear: both;
}

#container nav ul li ul {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    display: none;
}
#container nav ul li:hover ul{
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">News</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a>Football News</a></li>
          <li><a>Team News</a></li>
          <li><a>Players News</a></li>
          <li><a>Other News</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About us</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can select only the first `ul` with direct children selector `>`, then it works.

```
#container nav > ul li {
  float: left;
  width: 100px;
  height: 40px;
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
  text-align: center;
  border-right: solid #fff 1px;
  border-bottom: solid #fff 1px;
  line-height: 40px;
  opacity: 0.8;
}
```